# how to post a text file to jasper reports server using rest v2 with json

Tags: json, rest, jasper-reports, http-post, jasperserver

I am trying to send a simple txt file to the JasperReports server (5.6.0 release) using a POST/json request.  I keep getting back client 400 error after the post.  I have read the docs but cannot figure out what is wrong.  If someone could post the exact headers and json content for a sample request to send a small txt file, I would greatly appreciate it.  One thing I cannot understand is if the post headers are correct.  There is much discussion in http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v56/v2resources-service in the "Content Header Type" section but there are no concrete exampes so I am not sure what is supposed to be given for the header for say a "txt" file (I am just using the vanilla 'Content-type': 'application/json' but I susplect this migh be wrong).

Below are my headers and content (I have edited it for readability and the content is uu64 encoded):

```
Post URL=http://jasperserver:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/resources/Reports/images/xyzzy
JsonData=
{   
    "content": 
        "3eHJ3eHJ3eCsgMSBBZG1pbmlzdHJhdG9ycyBOb25lICAgICAgI
            [clipped]
        sIDI5IDA5OjU2IHNjcmlwdHMKZHJ3eHJ3eHJ3eCsgMSBBZG1pb",
    "type": "txt", 
    "label": "Sample Label"
}
PostHeaders={'Content-type': 'application/json', 'accept': 'application/json'}
```

Comment: I was able to figure this out.  The problem was in fact my post header.  It needed to be:

    PostHeaders={'Content-type': 'application/repository.file+json', 'accept': 'application/json'}

Everything else I showed in my question was correct.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out.  The problem was in fact my post header.  It needed to be:

```
PostHeaders={
    'Content-type': 'application/repository.file+json', 
    'accept': 'application/json'
}
```

Everything else I showed in my question was correct.